# I can't figure out how to open specific steam games from the terminal

Tags: command-line, steam

How do I open Garry's mod from the terminal? I want to know how because I am creating code to launch Steam games through python, I have searched the web but I can't find the answer I am looking for Please help. my Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Do you know the game id?  try steam steam://rungameid/558990

Comment: it works! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find your game id (from your home directory, look in .steam/debian-installation/userdata/xxxxxxx/ , or look in the .desktop file), run the game from a terminal with the following:

```
steam steam://rungameid/123456
```

Comment: I found my app ids from just searching them up on the internet and it worked